# Discord.js v 12.5.1 overwriting permissions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a problem with this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied
> parameter is not a User nor a Role.

I tried almost every single fix I know, tried to looking to api for discover what is wrong but I did not get any solution.

Here's the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../../config.json');

module.exports = {
    name: "new",
    category: "tickets",
    description: "Vytvorí nový ticket",
    usage: "[príkaz | alias]",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        message.delete();
        let [parent, support, supervisor] = [config.tickets.category, message.guild.roles.cache.get(config.tickets.roles.support), message.guild.roles.cache.get(config.tickets.roles.supervisor)];
        let co = true;

        function check() {
            let channels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === 'text' && ch.name.startsWith('ticket-'));
            channels.forEach(channel => {
                if(channel.topic.includes(message.author.id)) co = false;
            });
        }
        check();

        if(!co) {
            let embed = new MessageEmbed().addField(':x: Error 404', 'Už máš otvorený ticket. Prosím ukonči ho predtým ako vytvoríš ďalší!').setColor('RED');
            return message.channel.send({embed: embed});
        }

        let ticket = await message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.author.username}`, 'text');

        let ch = await message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === parent);
        if(ch && ch.type === 'category') ticket.setParent(ch.id);
        
        ticket.setTopic(message.author.id);

        ticket.overwritePermissions([message.guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: false, VIEW_CHANNEL: false, READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: false }]);
        ticket.overwritePermissions([message.author.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: true, VIEW_CHANNEL: true, READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true }]);
        if(support) ticket.overwritePermissions([support.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: true, VIEW_CHANNEL: true, READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true }]);
        if(supervisor) ticket.overwritePermissions([supervisor.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: true, VIEW_CHANNEL: true, READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true, MANAGE_MESSAGES: true }]);
        let embed = new MessageEmbed().setColor('BLUE').setAuthor(`Vitaj ${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL).setDescription(config.tickets.messages.welcome);
        ticket.send({embed: embed});

        embed = new MessageEmbed().setColor('GREEN').addField(`✅ Ticket Vytvorený`, `Úspešne vytvorený tvoj ticket <#${ticket.id}>`);
        message.channel.send({embed: embed});
    }
};
```

The thing is that this code does not overwrite the Permissions.

```
ticket.overwritePermissions([message.guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: false, VIEW_CHANNEL: false, READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: false }]);
ticket.overwritePermissions([message.author.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: true, VIEW_CHANNEL: true, READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true }]);
if(support) ticket.overwritePermissions([support.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: true, VIEW_CHANNEL: true, READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true }]);
if(supervisor) ticket.overwritePermissions([supervisor.id, { SEND_MESSAGES: true, VIEW_CHANNEL: true, READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true, MANAGE_MESSAGES: true }]);
```

Any help for this? Will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after discovering and trying every thing I got a fix. Just posting this for someone who will finding help. The bug was that every `overwritePermissions()` tried overwrite permissions for its own and there was bad syntax too. Just replaced it with the following code and everything works correctly.

```
ticket.overwritePermissions([
            {
                id: message.guild.roles.everyone.id,
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
            {
                id: message.author.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
            },
            {
                id: support.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
            },

            {
                id: supervisor.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'MANAGE_MESSAGES'],
            },
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace 'overwritePermissions()' with 'updateOverwrite()'

Comment: Tried it after submitting this question with the first line of code. It worked but after replacing it for all I got same error. So then I tried put it back to only first code and it didn't work. I don't know what happened and I can't make it work again as it worked in first try. Then I tried also deleting cache but nothing changed.